# How can I get the full name & col number from specific line

Tags: tcl

I have 2 lines in a table as in the below example.
for each word I want to get the name and the col number.
The problem is to get the full name that locate in 2 rows as "Delay Mean"

How can I get the full name & col number?

```
       Edge   Fanout   Load      Slew        Delay       Delay       Delay       Incr        User     Total    Arrival      Arrival      Arrival      Timing Point                     Cell              Generated Clock        
                                             Mean        Sigma                   Delay       Derate   Derate   Mean         Sigma        Time                                                            Adjustment
```

Code:

```
    foreach line $rpt {
    if {[regexp -all ".*Edge.*Fanout.*" $line]} {
        foreach arg [regexp -all -inline ".*Edge.*Fanout.*" $line] {
                set first_line_table($arg) [lsearch $line $arg]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What separates columns? Tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the words are separated by *2 or more spaces* and that each heading line ends with 2 or more spaces:

```
set fh [open $filename r]
set lines [split [read -nonewline $fh] \n]

set indices [regexp -all -indices -inline {\S+(?:\s\S+)?\s{2,}} [lindex $lines 0]]

foreach pair $indices {
    lassign $pair start end
    lappend headings [join [lmap line $lines {
        string trim [string range $line $start $end]
    }]]
}

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $headings]} {incr i} {
    puts "column [expr {$i+1}] is <[lindex $headings $i]>"
}
```

```
column 1 is <Edge >
column 2 is <Fanout >
column 3 is <Load >
column 4 is <Slew >
column 5 is <Delay Mean>
column 6 is <Delay Sigma>
column 7 is <Delay >
column 8 is <Incr Delay>
column 9 is <User Derate>
column 10 is <Total Derate>
column 11 is <Arrival Mean>
column 12 is <Arrival Sigma>
column 13 is <Arrival Time>
column 14 is <Timing Point >
column 15 is <Cell >
column 16 is <Generated Clock Adjustment>
```

There is a trailing space for the headers that don't have a 2nd line part. You can add another `string trim` if that's unwanted.

Comment: Can you explain the below command?
`regexp -all -indices -inline {\S+(?:\s\S+)?\s{2,}`